# Find href attributes with find_elements_by_class_name in Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium

Using Selenium with Python.

I've got pages full of links with a class called item-title. I'm trying to iterate through the pages and compile a list of all the link texts and the href attributes that go with them. I want to output the titles and links to a csv file.  Here is my code:

```
myLinks=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("item-title")
for link in myLinks:
    out.write(link.text)
    out.write (",") 
    out.write(link.get_attribute("href"))
    out.write("\n")
```

The line that outputs the href value gives the following error:

TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Tried the following:

```
myLinks=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("item-title")
for link in myLinks:
    out.write(link.text)
    out.write (",") 
    out.write(str(link.get_attribute("href")))
    out.write("\n")
```

Error went away, link text is coming through okay, but now the href is coming through as 'None'

Edit to add the HTML

```
<div class="item-title">
    <span class="icons-pinned"></span>
    <span class="icons-solved"></span>
    <span class="icons-locked"></span>
    <span class="icons-moved"></span>
    <span class="icons-type"></span>
    <span class="icons-reply"></span>
    <a href="/mylink">My title</a>
</div>
```

I think I see the issue now. The  is a child element of the div, I need to target that, don't I?

Comment: Seeing the html might be helpful

Comment: Thanks, you've reminded me to look closer at the HTML and I think I see the issue now

Answer (score 1):

As per the HTML you have shared, the `link texts` and the `href attributes` are not within the node identified as **`find_elements_by_class_name("item-title")`**. Rather they are within the decendent **`<a>`** tag. Hence instead of using **`find_elements_by_class_name("item-title")`** we have to use either **`find_elements_by_xpath`** or **`find_elements_by_css_selector`** as follows :

- Using **`find_elements_by_css_selector`** :

  ```
  myLinks=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.item-title > a")
  for link in myLinks:
      out.write(link.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
      out.write (",") 
      out.write(link.get_attribute("href"))
      out.write("\n")
  ```
- Using **`find_elements_by_xpath`** :

  ```
  myLinks=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='item-title']/a")
  for link in myLinks:
      out.write(link.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
      out.write (",") 
      out.write(link.get_attribute("href"))
      out.write("\n")
  ```